# Jenkins Build with git submodules

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, git-submodules

I'm kinda new to Jenkins, I've done some work with it, but i am stumbling on question that i will explain right away:

Suppose i have the following folder structure:

```
>Project_Folder  
>> FolderA  
>>>FolderA.1

>> FolderB  
>>> FolderB.1  
>>> FolderB.2  

>> FolderC
```

**FolderA.1**, **FolderB.1** and **FolderB.2** have Visual Basic projects inside and i have then in **different git submodules**. (So, Project_Folder is the parent git repository).

**FolderC** has some shared files that are needed by all projects (A.1, B.1 and B.2) and **is not** a submodule, it's merely present in the parent repository.

I need those shared folder items to build the projects, but only cloning the submodule will not bring them attached, obviously.

All the .vbp files have the path to the shared folder like `../../FolderC/shared_item.cls`

In Jenkins, i wanted to add the individual submodules to different Pipelines, so that it would trigger when changes were made to that single repository. If i add the parent repo, it would be too inefficient since it would clone the entire repo and the specific submodule AND the job would be triggered every time a change was made to the parent instead of only to the child...

**Questions**:

```
Is it possible to grab the shared folder and clone only the child submodule?
```

**OR**

```
Is it possible to clone the parent and a specific submodule, 
BUT trigger the Pipeline build ONLY when the submodule is updated and not the parent?
```

What do you suggest me to do?
Many Thanks!

Comment: How are your hooks working? If it is easy to trigger a build when the submodule is updated, this sounds like the best option.

Comment: My Jenkins is in specific machine in a private network so, since the hook would run in the repository server, it would not be able to access my jenkins server